# HTML <input type="date" not validating min attribute correctly

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-validate

I have a form with a date field. The field is required and should not allow a date sooner than 2 days from the current date.

```
<input type="date" id="DayDate" name="DayDate" 
    class="form-control day-date input-validation-error" min="2023-05-09" 
    placeholder="Date" data-val="true" data-val-required="Date is required." required />

<span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="DayDate"
    data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

The calendar appears to format correctly and disables all days preceding 2023-05-09.

Selecting any date that is enabled outputs a validation error of `Please enter a value greater than or equal to NaN.`

I tried adding the following rule in jQuery:

```
    $("#DayDate").rules("add",
        {
            required: true,
            min: "2023-05-09",
            messages: {
                required: "Required",
                min: "2 Day Minimum"
            }
        });
    });
```

Even after the above code, the control's rules.min value says NaN.

Can't the min attribute be used for an `input type=date` control? I'm missing a detail, but I don't see it.

Comment: The `min` rule is working as designed.  Refer to the documentation.  `min` only takes a number, hence the `NaN` (Not a Number) error.  https://jqueryvalidation.org/min-method/  If you want a rule that evaluates dates then you'll need to write a custom method for that.

Comment: Using min, I can disable the days preceding the min set date. Though validation isn't working and I understand what you're saying. So how can a custom method disable dates in the dropdown UI? For example, minDate set to `2023-05-18` and all days prior to that date are disabled?

Comment: You're mixing HTML5 validation attributes and elements with jQuery Validate plugin.   The HTML5 attributes/elements do not translate exactly how you want, or how you expect, over to jQuery Validate.  If you want to use HTML5, then use HTML5 all by itself.  Otherwise, change it into a `type="text"` field along with a custom jQuery Validate method.